# Client side rendering and skipping server rendering approach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, template-engine

I want to render my pages client-side to help keep the load off the server and keep down traffic. I understand that the first call to the server normally results in that the server must render the page requested and then sends that page to the user. When the user interacts with the page the javascript takes over the routing, which sends requests to the server for a specific view which then is updated via javascript on the client.

I was thinking if this approach exists or not and if it is viable.

Let's say i wish to go to the address:

```
www.example.com/about
```

Is there an approach which attaches the `/about` as an argument to the html page/javascript code (same that serves `www.example.com/`) from the server. When the dom is ready on the client it sends a request to the server for the `/about` data, which with the response updates the clients views. This would mean skipping the server side rendering completely.

Or am I crazy?

Comment: since it is tagged as Angular, I assume you know about it, right?
Then check out Angular-router which is the module that does exactly that.

Comment: @MrE Indeed! I tagged it as I normally use these platforms and this post might be interesting for those developers. Yes I know it doesn't *really* have anything to do with them specifically.

Comment: an example here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: I believe this answer is one (if not the only) way to achieve what you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: @MrE I see! I haven't dived deep into AngularJS yet, good link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not crazy. This is the way that most single page application (SPA) frameworks, like AngularJS work.

For example, the way that I typically configure a webserver for AngularJS is to have the following routes:

- `/pub/<relative_file_path>` just serves the static file specified by `<relative_file_path>`, such as all the JS, HTML partials and CSS.
- `/api/<whatever>` is where all endpoints which the client accesses via AJAX live
- *everything else* just returns `index.html`, which is a static file that contains the whole page with references to the JS, CSS and markup.

Thus when you go to `www.example.com/about`, you will get the `index.html` page, which tells the browser to download the JS for the whole application, which includes the client-side routing configuration. Once the application starts, it sees that the location is `www.example.com/about`, and says "I know about `/about`, I will go to that page!".

Of course, by "go to that page", I mean "fetch the partial HTML for that page, and fetch any data via AJAX". No visible page refresh/change happens.

Comment: Ah so it automatically checks the url some part in the loading. The question is; will it show the original index content first (as if the user started there) and *then* request the `/about` page? If so I'm guessing it will result in a flickering effect as it updates?

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little bit flickery, but it's not usually super noticeable. In fact, what you usually see is the "shell/skeleton" UI briefly first, then the main content area gets filled in when it loads. It's usually fast enough for most use cases.